# Need help understanding why Backbone.js route events do (or don't) fire

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following routes (hope nobody minds my using Coffeescript):

```
class MyRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    'games': 'games'
    'games/latest': 'latestGames'

  games: -> 
  latestGames: ->
```

I want to be able to respond to routing events outside of `MyRouter` like so:

```
App.myRouter.on('route:games', -> alert('games'))
App.myRouter.on('route:games/latest', -> alert('games/latest'))
```

When I go to `#games`, I get a 'games' alert. When I go to `#games/latest`, I do not get a 'games/latest' alert. When I navigate away from `#games`, I get a 'games' alert.

My questions are:

1. Why don't I get a 'games/latest' alert when I navigate to `#games/latest`?
2. Why do I get a 'games' alert when I navigate away from `#games`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was applying `on` to the URL fragment, when I should be applying it to the action.

```
App.myRouter.on('route:games', -> alert('games'))
App.myRouter.on('route:latestGames', -> alert('games/latest'))
```